# Ethernet NetXtreme BCM57786 not working on elementaryOS 6.1, though had been working on 5.1

Tags: drivers, ethernet

The Ethernet Card of my Apple MacBookPro10,1 is a "NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe". It is not working any more since I have installed elementaryOS 6.1. With elementaryOs 5.1 it had worked seemlessly.

I've done a [hardware probe](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=6354f13944) and it says: "Driver is not found or not configured. We have not found a driver for the device in any Linux kernel versions up to 5.19 (according to the LKDDb) or known additional packages."

So it seems, there has never been a dedicated linux driver for this particular ethernet card, but it has been working with another (default?) driver.

Is there a way to pick the ethernet driver of elementaryOS 5.1 and install it on 6.1?

Comment: Try the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671573/broadcom-netxtreme-ii-bcm57810-10-gigabit-ethernet-appearing-as-unclaimed-on-ubu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of @Vlad helped me get on the track. As discussed [here](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Iniciantes-no-Linux/Elementary-Os-nao-conecta-no-Wi-fi) in brazilian Portuguese, I had to:

- In Terminal, type

  - `sudo apt-get update`
  - `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
- restart

Note that according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671688/414821) answer and Vlad's comment, I first did:

- In Terminal, type

  - `sudo apt install linux-firmware linux-modules-$(uname -r)`
  - `sudo modprobe -v bnx2x`
- restart

... but I don't think it is necessary here, as the latter installs the drivers for the model "BCM57810", not "BCM57786".